ios mail app block hyperlink with image in email template. what is the solution?

enter image description here
this is sturcture, I insert a image as child of a hyperlink.
Works in every platform. But link bloks in ios mail app.
But in simple hyperlink, it's works.
I expect links over image should works in ios mail app.
How can I do this?
